# Script tags in RTE AEM 6.1

Tags: aem, rte

I am trying to create a Editor component that will take inline javascript.
I understand that I can use clientlibs folder for loading JS, but some of the video CDN folks require you to put embed tags with JavaScript in the editor, and I think some of that is also used for rapid development. Currently with the state of RTE, I cannot put a script `<script/>` tag even after extending it, as it strips it out and only takes the html tags. 
Could you please provide any insight if this could be doable in AEM 6.1

Here's what I have tried:

1. I looked at several post didn't got a clue
2. extended RTE using Adobe's documentation, but see a script button, that only takes html tags.
3. looked for hacks that could tell me what part of the code is tripping out `</script>` tags or could not execute js.
4. looked for some components out there that does that, found nothing
   so far.

Comment: In case you are using sightly, make sure you are setting the context properly while displaying the content entered in RTE

Comment: I am not using the sightly , I am just trying to understand how do i use script tags in the RTE.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to use rte as a code editor. providing authors with ability to insert executable code in rte is dangerous, to say the least. you may want to create a custom video component with required config.